# Hair Particle orientation on rigged object

Tags: rigging

So I made a brush object with some hair particles on the tip.
The object is fully rigged and functional.  The issue I get is when I try to rotate the object side to side.  It seems the hair particles do not follow the orientation of the object it self. I want it to point in the same direction as it is in default, but have had zero luck in figuring this out. The Particles Settings are under my Armature stack. Under the Particle Properties, I have use Modifier stack checked on.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Attached are the some screenshots.  The upright position being the default.  As you can see, when I rotate it, the hairs seem to want to point up.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you rig this with an armature? Usually, hair is static when you don't have Hair Dynamics enabled. Your modifier stack sounds fine.

Comment: Yes, I had the model done first, then I rigged it by creating an armature. The head of the brush is a different object, but controlled by the same armature. It orients finely on each pivot.
When I rotate the brush object alone, the hair particles follow perfectly. But when I rely on the rotation of the RIg, that's when the hairs start to do their own thing. Even with hair dynamics off, the hairs still wont cooperate.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to make it work.  Basically I applied the fur particles to just the surface area. I parented that to the main object, and parented it to the rig.
It works fine now for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

On the newest versions of Blender, you should drag the *Particles Modifier* on top of the stack, then, in *Object Mode*, click the button *Make Instances Real*.

This operation will spawn the hair as a mesh, then you have to parent it to the bone.